# How to tell whether current bash script was invoked from call script

Tags: java, linux, bash

I have a script that ideally will be used in two different ways. One, run stand-alone from command line. Two invoke from a service script located in /etc/init.d.

I would like the script (call it run_app.sh) to work as follows:

```
#/bin/bash
# this is run_app.sh. It should be able to be run stand-alone or called from another script

if [ invoked by a calling script ] then
   java -cp . -jar blah.jar  
else
   nohup java -cp . -jar blah.jar 2>&1 &
```

, so its the "invoked by a calling script" that I would need help with. Thank you.

Comment: How are you going to launch the service? SysVinit? Why would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to launch your script either by issuing `./run_app.sh` or the service. You can just use `$0`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is run_app.sh. It should be able to be run stand-alone or called from another script

this_script_name="run_app.sh"

if [ "$0" == "./${this_script_name}" ] then
   java -cp . -jar blah.jar  
else
   nohup java -cp . -jar blah.jar 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to find out how the script was called, I suggest to use a command line argument.

Script `app.sh`

```
#/bin/bash
# this is run_app.sh. It should be able to be run stand-alone or called from another script

if [ "$1" = "--service" ] then
   java -cp . -jar blah.jar  
else
   nohup java -cp . -jar blah.jar 2>&1 &
fi
```

Manually run the script as `app.sh`, from the calling script run `app.sh --service`.

If you need to pass additional command line arguments to your script, you might have to implement some better option parsing.

Note: Checking `$0` may work under certain conditions, but may not work in some other cases. Trying to find out details about the parent processes is even more difficult and fragile.

Another note: Your `java` command line arguments `-cp . -jar blah.jar` depend on the current directory. To make sure this works in all cases, the script should `cd` into the correct directory before calling `java`. e.g. `cd $(dirname "$0")` if the script is located in the same directory as `blah.jar`.